# dojo build nls path and data

Tags: javascript, dojo

I added a new layer in dojo build config as below:

```
releaseDir: "./my-build",
layers: {
    "myLib": {
        include: [
            "myFile1",
            "myFile2"
      ]
  }
}
```

After build, nls created under my-build folder, and include all locale files

> my-build/
>   -myLib.js
>   -nls
>     --myLib_en-us.js

In the html file, my dojoConfig is:

```
var dojoConfig = {
    async: true,
    cacheBust: false,
    paths: {
        "ah": "/hm-webapp/resources/scripts/ah",
        "i18n": '/hm-webapp/resources/i18n'
    },
    baseUrl: "/hm-webapp/resources/scripts/dojo/",
    locale: ""
};
```

and I am including my layer via a script tag:

```
<script src="/my-build/myLib.js">
</script>
```

But there is a

> 404 error for myLib_en-us.js

It seems that dojo automatically load nls files, but the request path is like this

> --/nls/myLib_en-us.js

There is no subpath "my-build" for the nls request.

My question is how to change the nls path to the build path.

Thanks.

Comment: What does your `dojoConfig` look like in the page that is loading the layer?  This sounds like an issue with that.  Also, how are you loading the layer itself, if that loads without issues but not the nls bundle?

Comment: Here is my dojoconfig
<pre>
var dojoConfig = {
   async : true,
   cacheBust : false,
   paths : {
    "ah" : "/hm-webapp/resources/scripts/ah",
    "i18n" : '/hm-webapp/resources/i18n'
   },
   baseUrl : "/hm-webapp/resources/scripts/dojo/",
   locale: ""
  };
</pre>
And layer is loaded in script tag:
<script src="/myLib.js"></script>

Comment: One more question:  where is the `hm-webapp/resources/scripts/dojo/` folder you set as your `baseUrl`, relative to the `my-build` structure you indicated in your question?

Comment: dojo is using another folder separately, the build does not include dojo build, I just want to test if my customized myLib.js is working, Thanks for your response.